# How to count days range by name between two input select in Java Script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is here some solutions how to count days between two select input only by day name of week with JavaScript? Or some demo in jsfiddle?

Example:

I Have two select tag inputs:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Sunday</option>
  <option value="2">Monday</option>
  <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="5">Thursday</option>
  <option value="6">Friday</option>
  <option value="7">Saturday</option>
</select> 

 <select>
  <option value="1">Sunday</option>
  <option value="2">Monday</option>
  <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="5">Thursday</option>
  <option value="6">Friday</option>
  <option value="7">Saturday</option>
</select> 

<input type="text" name="c_days">
```

If user select Friday in the first one and the Monday in the second one (its been result 3 days), should calculate the total number of days between the first and second select and put counted valuee into c_days input.

Thank for idea!

Comment: Have you tried using moment. Js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function updateResult() {
  // Get selections.
  var firstValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('#firstMenu').value);
  var secondValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('#secondMenu').value);
  // Calculate difference. If < 0, add 7 days.
  var difference = secondValue - firstValue;
  if (difference < 0) difference += 7;
  // Add value to input
  document.querySelector('#c_days').value = difference;
}

window.onload = function() {
  // Append functions to drop down menus.
  document.querySelector('#firstMenu').addEventListener('change', updateResult);
    document.querySelector('#secondMenu').addEventListener('change', updateResult);
};
```

```html
<select id="firstMenu">
  <option value="1">Sunday</option>
  <option value="2">Monday</option>
  <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="5">Thursday</option>
  <option value="6">Friday</option>
  <option value="7">Saturday</option>
</select> 

 <select id="secondMenu">
  <option value="1">Sunday</option>
  <option value="2">Monday</option>
  <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="5">Thursday</option>
  <option value="6">Friday</option>
  <option value="7">Saturday</option>
</select> 

<input type="text" name="c_days" id="c_days" value="0">
```

Comment: Same solution but different way, hence no need for an extra answer^^: https://jsfiddle.net/7r15eu9c/

Comment: Thank you very much! I'ts perfect!

Comment: With pleasure. Feel free to mark as answered if it did.